# On an iPad, how to create a left side menu to let the contents displayed at the centre according to the item tapped on the menu

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface, tableview

I am very new to iOS development. Currently, I am trying to develop an iPad app, which is used for taking orders in a restaurant. When I am trying to create the UI on an iPad, I want to create a left side menu to let the contents displayed at the centre according to the item tapped on the menu. Which is similar to this: http://www.dhtmlx.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/ipad_menu_final.jpg

As I am very new to the iOS development, can anybody tell me where I can learn iOS development step by step. And are they any samples of this kind of app that I can refer to?

Thanks very much!

Comment: use UISplitViewController. you'll find many tutorials online

Comment: http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2013/05/uisplitviewcontroller-landscape.html and http://www.raywenderlich.com/29469/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uisplitview-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many tutorials for creating split view application as links provided by @PratyushaTerli and otherwise you can use direect way as recommended by @antonio MG and there is another two good links for creating them which are : https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu  (good demos in it using story board or using xib's ) and you can look on project on github named - mmdrawercontroller. 
annother good project is [this](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNFrostedSidebar)

Answer (score 2):

As Antonio MG said, the easiest way to do this is with Master/Detail project in Xcode. It uses the `UISplitViewController` logic of one 'Master' controller which controls the appearance of detail content in the 'Slave' or 'Detail' controller aside.

The sample Xcode project should be enough to make you understand how `UISplitViewController` and its `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` work together. Or also checkout this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Master/Detail project and you will have the basic structure of that kind of behaviour. The rest is just customising the table and the cells.

Comment: some people told me to add two tableViews, one is for the menu categories on the left, the other is for the detail items at the centre, how does that sound?

Comment: I have implemented my own UISplitViewController clone, but it's not worth it. For most things, the provided UISplitViewController should be more than enough.